# Thymeleaf - how to add a Span to a dynamic text in a <h1> section

Tags: thymeleaf

We have a title for our page that we are building dynamically with `Thymeleaf`

```
<h1 th:text="'My name is' + ${person.name} + ' ' +${person.lastname}" ></h1>
```

And the outcome is:

```
<h1>My name is Inigo Montoya</h1>
```

Now, we like to color in red the name of the user.

In simple HTML + CSS we can do it like that:

```
span{
 color: red;
}

<h1>My name is <span>Inigo</span> Montoya</h1>
```

But how to do it correctly in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<h1>
  My name is <span th:text="${person.name}" /> [[${person.lastname}]]
</h1>
```